# Amazon S3 Upload Images from android Application ,Getting Access Denied Error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am Uploading the Images from my android Application to **Aws S3**.

I added Credetials Like **COGNITO_POOL_ID** and **BUCKET_NAME** in my Code.

Problem:

While Uploading image to S3 Bucket, **Loading more than 50%** then Showing below Error Message in Logcat.

Please help me to solve this issue.

```
12-14 10:50:00.366 19534-27351/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadTask: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: DBF63654656657)
12-14 10:50:00.466 19534-27211/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6928K, 60% free 5964K/14680K, paused 48ms, total 48ms
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19543/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo W/CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity: Error during upload: 11
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transfer failed.
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver$TransferContentObserver.onChange(TransferObserver.java:219)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:129)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:180)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
12-14 10:50:00.476 19534-19534/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Error 2:** Second time Relaunch the application

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0x6c637630: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity: Error during upload: 1
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transfer failed.
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver$TransferContentObserver.onChange(TransferObserver.java:219)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.database.ContentObserver.onChange(ContentObserver.java:129)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:180)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
12-14 12:03:52.080 9063-9063/com.knowledgeflex.amazondemo E/UploadActivity:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you have to give access to your bucket as public read/write

Comment: where i have to change access of Bucket?

Comment: @Nirus i changed the permission access to Everyone Upload ,delete .Its worked thanks for your help.

Comment: Granting public access to the bucket works, but it's not recommended because people with credentials can access it as well. Instead, consider granting access to the IAM role of the Cognito identity pool. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/iam-roles/.